# Сериализация данных, с++

Tags: c++, сериализация

Здравствуйте, у меня имеется проблема с сериализацией данных. В предыдущей теме я плохо раскрыл вопрос, решил ее удалить и заново его сформулировать.
По заданию я должен сделать свой контейнер похожий на `map<key,value>`, в котором ключ идет в древо, а валуе в файл , название коего является ключём.

Для выполнения этой части задания нам сказали использовать заранее определенные trait классы: KeySerializationTrait, FileTypeSerializationTrait.

```
template <typename T>
struct KeySerializationTrait {
    static std::string Serialize(const T& t) { std::stringstream ss; ss << t; return ss.str(); }
    static T Deserialize(const std::string& str) { T tmp;  std::stringstream(str) >> tmp; return tmp; }
};

template <typename T>
struct FileTypeSerializationTrait
{
    static void Serialize(std::ostream& fileStream, const T& item) { fileStream << item; }
    static T Deserialize(std::istream& fileStream) { T tmp; fileStream >> tmp; return tmp; }
};

template <>
struct FileTypeSerializationTrait <std::string> {
    static void Serialize(std::ostream& fileStream, const std::string& str) {
        fileStream << str;
    }
    static std::string Deserialize(std::istream& fileStream) {
        return std::string((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(fileStream)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
    };
};
```

Задание гласит, что пользователь контейнера должен обеспечить подходящую сериализацию и десериализацию своих типов данных в форме специализации шаблонов.

Проблема в том, что я не понимаю, что это значит.

Например, если я хочу написать в дереве функцию сохранения переменной в файл, как мне использовать эти шаблоны?

Дерево имеет шаблоны template  где Keyэто тип ключа, а mapped_type это тип переменной(которую я должен сохранять в файл) :

мой код элемента Авл дерева, тут есть `getValue` и `setValue`.

```
struct Tree_ // структура для представления узлов дерева
{
    Key key;
    unsigned char height;
    Tree_* parent;
    Tree_* left;
    Tree_* right;
    Tree_(Key k) { key = k; left = right = parent = 0; height = 1; }
    //читает с файла
    mapped_type getValue()
    {
        // как я понимаю, сюда нужно добавить эти структуры, но когда я их инициирую в классе, компилятор их не видит в структуре.
        return key;
    }
    //запись в файл
    bool setValue(mapped_type a)
    {

        return true;
    }
};
```

Update::
Попробовал реализовать гет и сет.
На данный момент они выглядят так:

```
    mapped_type getValue()
    {
        FileTypeSerializationTrait<mapped_type> FileTypeSerialization;
        std::ifstream ifs(getFileName(key));//getFileName это перевод кея в стринг
        mapped_type tmp= FileTypeSerialization.Deserialize(ifs);
        ifs.close();
        return tmp;
    }
    void setValue(mapped_type a)
    {
        FileTypeSerializationTrait<mapped_type> FileTypeSerialization;
        std::ofstream ofs(getFileName(key));//getFileName это перевод кея в стринг
        FileTypeSerialization.Serialize(ofs, a);
        ofs.close();
    }
```

Вопрос таков, коректно ли я их использую?

Comment: Думаю, у Вас не хватает ещё целостности приведённого кода, чтобы люди здесь могли понять его и что-то рекомендовать. Непонятно, что за тип `AVL_Tree`, непонятно, как `Tree_` взаимосвязан с кодом выше, а также, скорее всего, структура тоже шаблонная, у неё есть некие `Key` и `mapped_type`, хотя они не указаны.

Comment: А эта конструкция, `template <> struct FileTypeSerializationTrait <std::string>`, позволяет определить особенное поведение для конкретных типов шаблона. В Вашем случае причина этому - особая форма считывания строки в `Deserialize`.

Comment: я у простил вопрос еще сильнее, сведя все к тому, как в getValue и в setValue реализовать запись при помощи этих шаблнов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваше задание таково:

> По заданию я должен сделать свой контейнер похожий на map, в котором ключ идет в древо, а валуе в файл, название коего является ключом.

А теперь Ваш код это и делает. Переводит ключ в строку, сохраняет, загружает по нему. Но я бы не выносил `getFileName` отдельно. К тому же, Вам не нужно создавать экземпляры структур — их методы статические.

```
    mapped_type getValue()
    {
        std::ifstream ifs(KeySerializationTrait<Key>::Serialize(key));
        mapped_type tmp= FileTypeSerializationTrait<mapped_type>::Deserialize(ifs);
        ifs.close();
        return tmp;
    }
    void setValue(mapped_type a)
    {
        std::ofstream ofs(KeySerializationTrait<Key>::Serialize(key));
        FileTypeSerializationTrait<mapped_type>::Serialize(ofs, a);
        ofs.close();
    }
```

Кстати, как я понял, Вы не использовали `KeySerializationTrait::Deserialize`. Как я понял, этот метод Вам понадобится после сериализации самого дерева, а не только его узлов. То есть, при сериализации дерева сохраняются узлы в файлы, потом ключи в отдельном файле. И при десериализации сначала считываются ключи, преобразуются к нужному типу, затем уже значения узлов из своих файлов.

Comment: @Demolver пожалуйста :)